# Why does MySQL explicit predicate locking disallow INSERT statements outside of the predicate lock

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking

Assuming we have the following database tables:

```
create table department (
    id bigint not null, 
    budget bigint not null, 
    name varchar(255), 
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

create table employee (
    id bigint not null, 
    name varchar(255), 
    salary bigint not null, 
    department_id bigint, primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

alter table employee 
add constraint FK_department_id 
foreign key (department_id) 
references department (id)
```

And we have 2 `departments`:

```
insert into department (name, budget, id) 
values ('Hypersistence', 100000, 1)

insert into department (name, budget, id) 
values ('Bitsystem', 10000, 2)
```

And 3 `employees` in the first department:

```
insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, 'John Doe 0', 30000, 0)

insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, 'John Doe 1', 30000, 1)

insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, 'John Doe 2', 30000, 2)
```

Assuming we have two concurrent users: Alice and Bob.

First, Alice locks all the employee belonging to the 1st `department` and also gets the sum of salaries for that particular `department`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE department_id = 1 
FOR UPDATE

SELECT SUM(salary) 
FROM employee 
where department_id = 1
```

Now, in the meanwhile, it's expected that Bob cannot insert a new `employee` using the same `department_id`:

```
insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, `Carol`, 9000, 4)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: 
    Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

So, the lock prevented Bob from issuing an insert against the same predicate.

However, the same exception is thrown even if Bob tries to insert an `employee` in a different `department`:

```
insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (2, `Dave`, 9000, 5)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: 
    Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

This last insert statement is using the 2nd `department_id`, so this row should not overlap with the select statement for which we acquired a predicate lock.

Why does MySQL prevent the second insert which is not overlapping with the predicate lock acquired by the first transaction?

The same behavior can be observed on SQL Server as well.

### Update

When changing the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED, the predicate lock does not prevent any of the two insert statements issued by Bob.

That could be explained if taking into consideration the following statements from [this Percona blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/):

> In REPEATABLE READ every lock acquired during a transaction is held
> for the duration of the transaction.
>
> In READ COMMITTED the locks that did not match the scan are released
> after the STATEMENT completes.

However, it's still interesting to find out why the predicate locking works as it does on REPEATABLE READ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is locking between 1 and the next value in the employee table.  Since there is no next-value, it is locking until the `supremum pseudo-record`.  This can be seen in `information_schema.innodb_locks`:

```
mysql> select * from innodb_locks;
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+
| lock_id        | lock_trx_id | lock_mode | lock_type | lock_table        | lock_index | lock_space | lock_page | lock_rec | lock_data              |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+
| 28275:1448:3:1 | 28275       | X         | RECORD    | `test`.`employee` | PRIMARY    |       1448 |         3 |        1 | supremum pseudo-record |
| 28273:1448:3:1 | 28273       | X         | RECORD    | `test`.`employee` | PRIMARY    |       1448 |         3 |        1 | supremum pseudo-record |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

If you change the test-case slightly so there is a row in employees for dept-id=2, and then try and add an employee for dept-id=3, it will work.  Example:

```
create table department (
    id bigint not null, 
    budget bigint not null, 
    name varchar(255), 
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table employee (
    id bigint not null, 
    name varchar(255), 
    salary bigint not null, 
    department_id bigint, primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


alter table employee 
add constraint FK_department_id 
foreign key (department_id) 
references department (id);


insert into department (name, budget, id) 
values ('Hypersistence', 100000, 1);

insert into department (name, budget, id) 
values ('Bitsystem', 10000, 2);

insert into department (name, budget, id) 
values ('XX', 10000, 3);


insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, 'John Doe 0', 30000, 0);

insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (1, 'John Doe 1', 30000, 1);

insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (2, 'John Doe 2', 30000, 2);


start transaction;

SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE department_id = 1 
FOR UPDATE;


# new session

insert into employee (department_id, name, salary, id) 
values (3, 'Dave', 9000, 5)
```

Comment: hi @Morgan Tocker excellent + 1. This behavior (to take-consider the next key) occurs ONLY WHEN THERE IS a secondary index, right? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB locks only the rows that are being used, but when Alice is doing:

```
SELECT SUM(salary) 
FROM employee 
where department_id = 1
```

I think all the table is locked because she is using all the table rows in her transaction (although the transaction is just reading the table).

Comment: Even if I remove this query, and Alice just issues the FOR UPDATE statement, nothing changes. Both Bob's insert statements are going to time out.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)(for Repeatable Read isolation level):

> - For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only the index record found, not the gap before it.
> - For other search conditions, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range (this is your case).

When you execute the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE department_id = 1 
FOR UPDATE
```

the `where` clause condition check does depend on a non-indexed `department_id` column hence a full table scan should be done for finding all the matching rows. In Repeatable Read isolation level Innodb locks all the scanned records until transaction Rollback or Commit, doesn't matter if the condition matches the row or not, also Gap Locks are applied to the gap before each record and after the last record in Clustered Index. Hence you get a fully locked table where nothing can be inserted, updated or deleted from any other transaction until the current one does Commit or Rollback.

I've recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452571/why-does-mysql-lock-the-table-in-repeatable-read-isolation-level-upon-executing) which might be interesting to you as well.