# when exactly does a lock pseudo-record supremum occur?

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index, non-clustered-index, rowlocking

**I need a example, please**

What do you mean by applying the lock to a pseudo-record?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-next-key-locks

> For the last interval, the next-key lock locks the gap above the
> largest value in the index and the **“supremum” pseudo-record** having a
> value higher than any value actually in the index. The supremum is not
> a real index record, so, in effect, this next-key lock locks only the
> gap following the largest index value.

Here is an example, but:

[Lock-data:supremum pseudo-record in MySQL5.7.11 with REPEATABLE-READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326846/lock-datasupremum-pseudo-record-in-mysql5-7-11-with-repeatable-read)

I don't understand the answer to this question, **it confuses me because it is a single search condition with UNIQUE INDEX**

Comment: Why do you need an example?

Comment: hi @ysth, in some cases it is difficult to describe why it is used.

Comment: check the edit to my question @ysth, please

Comment: what is a single search condition?  show why this matters to you, show the problem you are trying to solve, and you are much more likely to get an answer that helps you.  as is, I don't really see anything to say beyond what your link and the links in it say.

Comment: If I apply the lock on id = 1 the pseudo-record is not locked even though it is the last record in the index. So why does it apply on id = 2?

Comment: So that if you do another select for id=2 in that transaction it gets the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supremum lock is created when the gap lock is at the end of the table. That is, your transaction locks a gap, and there is no existing record greater than the range you requested.

In the example you linked to:

Session 1:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

insert into a values(1);

begin;
select * from a where id=2 for update;
```

In the default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE-READ, this locks a gap from id=2 to infinity, which is the supremum.

Then in session 2:

```
begin;
insert into a values(3);
...waits...
```

The gap lock held by session 1 covers everything from 2 to infinity, so it blocks an insert of id 3.

Whereas if session 1 had a transaction isolation level of READ-COMMITTED, then it doesn't acquire the gap lock.

Session 1:

```
set transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';

begin;
select * from a where id=2 for update;
```

Session 2:

```
mysql> insert into a values(3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: hello @Bill Karwin `The gap lock held by session 1 covers everything from 2 to infinity, so it blocks an insert of id 3`- I understand, but even if id = 2 DOES NOT EXIST in the table, is the lock still applied from 2 (or any id that does not actually NOT EXIST) to infinity? If id = 2 existed it would only apply a record lock (no gap lock) on id = 2, right? Speaking of REPEATABLE-READ - thanks

Comment: or is that because id = 1 is the last record? @Bill Karwin

Comment: It's because id=1 is the last record. The non-existing row where id=2 is a gap, so there's a gap lock, and because that gap extends to infinity, the supremum is locked.